# Is there a way to kill all the visible dialog as an activity is destroyed?

Tags: android

I am asking this because I am always getting the Activity has leaked window.. error

Couldn't figure out a way to destroy some of the dialogs on activity destroy since these dialogs
are dynamically generated outside the activity(on some listener).

So is there a way for android to detect and kill all the visible/live dialogs?
Thanks

Comment: As long as you have some sort of reference to them in your activity you should be able to dismiss them all. Do you keep these dialogs in a variable, or do you just launch them and have no way to access them later?

Comment: My thought was there could be some case where you lunch a dialog from another customized buttom or widget so you don't have access to the dialog in the activity... So I was looking for some sort of parent-child relationship between activity and the dialogs opened on it. If I kill the activity, before that I kill all the dialogs that's depending on it... not sure if my question make any sense

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you can keep a member reference to your dialogs as you create them. Then you can check the `isShowing()` method to see if its showing. Then hide and destroy the dialogs that are showing.